# Flutter NSInternalInconsistencyException on iOS

Tags: ios, flutter

I am getting the following error on the crashanalytics dashboard:

```
1   CoreFoundation  __exceptionPreprocess (in CoreFoundation) + 220
2   libobjc.A.dylib objc_exception_throw (in libobjc.A.dylib) + 60
3   CoreAutoLayout  -[NSISEngine withAutomaticOptimizationDisabled:] (in CoreAutoLayout) + 0
4   CoreAutoLayout  -[NSISEngine _optimizeWithoutRebuilding] (in CoreAutoLayout) + 72
5   CoreAutoLayout  -[NSISEngine optimize] (in CoreAutoLayout) + 120
6   CoreAutoLayout  -[NSISEngine performPendingChangeNotifications] (in CoreAutoLayout) + 116
7   UIKitCore   -[UIView(Hierarchy) layoutSubviews] (in UIKitCore) + 500
8   UIKitCore   -[UIView(CALayerDelegate) layoutSublayersOfLayer:] (in UIKitCore) + 2592
9   QuartzCore  CA::Layer::layout_if_needed(CA::Transaction*) (in QuartzCore) + 532
10  QuartzCore  CA::Layer::layout_and_display_if_needed(CA::Transaction*) (in QuartzCore) + 136
11  QuartzCore  CA::Context::commit_transaction(CA::Transaction*, double, double*) (in QuartzCore) + 452
12  QuartzCore  CA::Transaction::commit() (in QuartzCore) + 704
13  QuartzCore  CA::Transaction::flush_as_runloop_observer(bool) (in QuartzCore) + 88
14  CoreFoundation  __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ (in CoreFoundation) + 36
15  CoreFoundation  __CFRunLoopDoObservers (in CoreFoundation) + 592
16  CoreFoundation  __CFRunLoopRun (in CoreFoundation) + 1052
17  CoreFoundation  CFRunLoopRunSpecific (in CoreFoundation) + 600
18  Flutter __NO_DSYM_FILE__
19  Flutter __NO_DSYM_FILE__
20  libsystem_pthread.dylib _pthread_start (in libsystem_pthread.dylib) + 148
21  libsystem_pthread.dylib thread_start (in libsystem_pthread.dylib) + 8
```

This crash sometimes occurs when the app did become active again.